# Highcharts with values from multiple JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, getjson

currently I have set the below Highchart code and I would like to replace my chart static data-series values, which is included inside the HTML file to be loaded from a JSON file.

The current code looks like below:

```
<!doctype html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div style "class:container; align:center">
  <div id="myChart" style="width: 315px; height: 315px; background-color: #FFF8EB; align:center"></div>
</div>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      title: {
        text: 'Comparison'
      },
      chart: {
        type: 'line',
        backgroundColor: "#FFF8EB",
        renderTo: 'myChart'
      },
      xAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Day of the Year'
        },
        tickInterval: 7,
        ceiling: 366,
        min: 1,
        max: 366,
        minPadding: 0.0,
        maxPadding: 0.0
      },

      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Kilometers'
        },
        tickInterval: 250,
        lineWidth: 1,
        minPadding: 0.0,
        maxPadding: 0.0,
        offset: 0,
        min: 0
      },
      labels: {
        align: 'right',
        step: 30,
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      },
      series: [{
          name: '2013',
          color: '#77B753',
          lineWidth: 3,
          data: [
            [64, 56.22],
            [128, 755.13],
            [160, 1412.96],
            [202, 2125.98],
            [236, 2947.44],
            [294, 3761.47],
            [358, 4097.91],
            [359, 4162.09],
            [362, 4450.29],
            [363, 4552.25]
          ]
        },
        {
          name: '2014',
          color: '#F29B68',
          lineWidth: 3,
          data: [
            [4, 21.73],
            [124, 1751.75],
            [204, 3741.57],
            [234, 4517.99],
            [273, 5386.65],
            [304, 6073.86],
            [327, 6276.24],
            [333, 6332.13],
            [359, 6615.71],
            [360, 6688.89],
            [360, 6711.41],
            [361, 6749.21],
            [362, 6835.68],
            [363, 6909.45]
          ]
        },
        {
          name: '2015',
          color: '#6193CF',
          lineWidth: 3,
          data: [
            [11, 31.9],
            [66, 406.6],
            [102, 1004.81],
            [115, 1498.8],
            [126, 1777.21],
            [154, 2535.4],
            [198, 3422.83],
            [216, 4063.94],
            [248, 4778.75],
            [279, 5388.67],
            [309, 5772.34],
            [314, 5772.34],
            [335, 5930.32],
            [359, 6433.87]
          ]
        }
      ]
    });
  });

</script>
</!doctype>
```

Is there a way to load the series data/values from a JSON file which looks like below:

```
[{"key":"154","value":38.91},{"key":"154","value":38.91},{"key":"158","value":136.46},{"key":"159","value":261.07},{"key":"165","value":275.09},{"key":"180","value":285.2},{"key":"186","value":303.49},{"key":"187","value":333.41},{"key":"189","value":369.3},{"key":"191","value":395.63},{"key":"196","value":456.42},{"key":"198","value":488.58},{"key":"200","value":518.69},{"key":"204","value":573.74},{"key":"206","value":637.92},{"key":"210","value":675.29},{"key":"212","value":732.73},{"key":"214","value":778.25},{"key":"218","value":828.53},{"key":"221","value":869.79},{"key":"225","value":925.21},{"key":"227","value":983.09},{"key":"244","value":1003.99},{"key":"247","value":1040.65},{"key":"249","value":1077.33},{"key":"251","value":1105.82},{"key":"253","value":1142.46},{"key":"259","value":1179.35},{"key":"266","value":1214.63},{"key":"271","value":1261.37},{"key":"272","value":1360.57},{"key":"273","value":1385.49},{"key":"291","value":1449.99},{"key":"294","value":1468.74},{"key":"297","value":1521.53},{"key":"358","value":1572.62},{"key":"359","value":1664.44},{"key":"361","value":1725.83},{"key":"362","value":1827.49},{"key":"363","value":1888.31},]
```

It should be like below but how do I call it/get the values in the "series":

```
var ytkm2013 = new Array();
    $.getJSON('https://link/to/my/data/2013-yearly-distance.json', function(data) {
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        ytkm2013.push([data[i].key, data[i].value]);
    }
    });
```

As I'm not the Java/JavaScript expert, any help/idea is welcome.

Thanks,
Al

Comment: I think you are looking for something called "AJAX"

Answer (score 2):

You have almost achieved what you want. You only need to do some minor changes.

First of all, your chart is showing three data series, but your JSON example has only one data array so my example below is for one data array.

First thing that you need to do is putting the chart code inside the `$.getJSON` callback since `$.getJSON` returns a promise so you should instantiate the chart only after the data comes back and you process it.

After you have processed and added all data to the `ytkm2014` array, you simply pass that array the series (as per example below).

It should look like this:

```
var ytkm2013 = new Array();

$.getJSON('https://link/to/my/data/2013-yearly-distance.json', function(data) {
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ytkm2013.push([data[i].key, data[i].value]);

    var chart = $("#myChart").highcharts({
      title: {
        text: 'Comparison'
      },
      chart: {
        type: 'line',
        backgroundColor: "#FFF8EB",
        renderTo: 'myChart'
      },
      xAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Day of the Year'
        },
        tickInterval: 7,
        ceiling: 366,
        min: 1,
        max: 366,
        minPadding: 0.0,
        maxPadding: 0.0
      },

      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Kilometers'
        },
        tickInterval: 250,
        lineWidth: 1,
        minPadding: 0.0,
        maxPadding: 0.0,
        offset: 0,
        min: 0
      },
      labels: {
        align: 'right',
        step: 30,
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      },
      series: [{
        name: '2013',
        color: '#77B753',
        lineWidth: 3,
        data: ytkm2013
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

I am not sure if it's best practice to make multiple calls to get different files, but if you still want to do it, you need to make sure all of them are loaded when you create the chart. You can try something like this:

```
data2013 = [];
data2014 = [];
data2015 = [];

$.getJSON('http://link2013', function (data) {
    //populate data2013

    $.getJSON('http://link2014', function (data) {

        //populate data2014

        $.getJSON('http://link2015', function (data) {

            //populate data2015

            //create the chart

        });

    });

});
```

If you have multiple series, you have to pass them to the `series` array as individual objects. The way to do it is like this:

```
series : [{
        name : '2013',
        color : 'red',
        lineWidth : 3,
        data : ytkm2013
    }, {
        name : '2014',
        color : 'blue',
        lineWidth : 3,
        data : ytkm2014
    }, {
        name : '2015',
        color : 'green',
        lineWidth : 3,
        data : ytkm2015
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice that the code has to be placed inside the getJson function. I still have an open point, how do I read the data with two or more JSON files? the chart should print values/year, which are stored in different yearly files. <br> the data I would call like `data: ytkm2013, ytkm2014`. Correct?